# How can I change the size of a MapPolygonSeries or a Polygon in a amCharts map?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I'm trying to make a heatmap with amCharts map, but some subdivisions are too small to be noticed. So I want to duplicate them and make them bigger on the side.
I tried duplicating the "special" polygon in a new MapPolygonSeries in the `beforedatavalidated` event, and later change the size with the `scale` property but it doesn't work. I only was able to move it, but not resize it.

For a better understanding, I made a CodePen using Kosovo as an example ( https://codepen.io/mariobirra/pen/gOWdeGa ). The blue polygon is the original, and the red one is the duplicated that I want to make it bigger.

Thanks,